# Can deadlock on database tables allows other queries to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I'm working around Microsoft SQL Server. I know that it uses parallel processing. But I want to know that, Say two update query on same table `X` turns into deadlock situation and 3rd query comes for another table `Y`, so SQL server will allow to run 3rd query or it'll block until SQL server recovers from deadlock? I tried to put scenario in image for better explanation.

[image]

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: that deadlock is going to get released uppon exception and query 3 will be able to go thru if i remember right

Comment: @Steve You mean query 3 won't execute until server recovers from deadlock right?

Comment: @VickyThakor If there are only locks in tableX, queries against tableY will run as usual. Locking the entire database instance for a query against another table would totally kill performance.

Comment: I mean the server is mostlikely going to remove the deadlock situation once it detects it by killing query 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most normal cases, Q<sub>3</sub> will be unaffected by the deadlock between Q<sub>1</sub> and Q<sub>2</sub>, because the locks taken will most likely be page or row locks against table *X*.

In fact, I can't imagine a scenario where a deadlock could occur if either of the first two queries obtains a table lock. But that's still table *X*, not *Y*, which has no existing locks held.

One possible case of Q<sub>3</sub> being blocked could occur if either of the others had previously accessed table *Y* within a transaction with the `holdlock` option. For example:

### Q<sub>1</sub>

```
begin transaction;

select * from Y where some_col = 'goats' with (updlock, holdlock);

update X set other_col = 'alpacas' where animal = 'best'; -- deadlock occurs here

commit transaction;
```

This is pretty contrived, but Q<sub>1</sub> has obtained an update lock on table *Y* that is held until the end of the transaction, blocking any selects from Q<sub>3</sub> until the transaction has complete (and the deadlock resolved).